# Formatting volume and mass units

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsformatter

Is there any mechanism to convert **volume** or **mass** units into local format like `NSDateFormatter` for date formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in iOS 7, but it's coming in iOS 8.

According to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ios8/#nsmassformatter), there'll be a `NSMassFormatter` and an `NSLengthFormatter`, both of which you can use to get formatted strings from.

In the meantime, you can use a third-party library like [DDUnitConverter](https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter) and convert the value to a string using NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: So, iOS 8 solves this problem and using this library is quite a good solution but.. built-in API is much more better.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 8 and OS X v10.10, Foundation contains NSFormatter classes for energy, length, and mass ([`NSEnergyFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/NSEnergyFormatter_Class/index.html), [`NSLengthFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/NSLengthFormatter_Class/index.html), [`NSMassFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/NSMassFormatter_Class/index.html)) but not temperature or volume :P

Until Apple provides a native solution, here's code for temperature and volume formatting:
https://github.com/jrc/Cocoa-Snippets/tree/master/Foundation/UnitFormatters

(HealthKit provides [`HKUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKUnit_Class/index.html) and [`HKQuantity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKQuantity_Class/index.html) for unit conversions but not unit formatting.)